# Corda - VaultQueryException: Please Register The Entity

Tags: corda

According to the [R3 documentation](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/api-persistence.html#custom-schema-registration):

> Tests using the DriverDSL will automatically register your custom schemas if they are in the same project structure as the driver call.

What if the custom schemas are **NOT** part of the same project structure as the driver call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the schemas are part of a cordapp, then including them in the driver dsl's creation should also load their schemas.

```kotlin
driver(DriverParameters(cordappsForAllNodes = cordappsForPackages("packages")))
```

Comment: Thanks, Dan. I've got that in my driver parameters already, so it might be an issue with how I'm specifying the cordapp packages.

Comment: ^ Seems it was my package names causing the problems. They were not specific enough.